# Get the epoch time and add it as a new column

Tags: linux, text-processing, date

I have the following tab separated input file, with timestamps in UTC. How can I calculate the epoch time an add it as a new column? It is a large file with over 60MM rows.

```
a   b
0   2020-03-03 15:46:52
1   2020-03-02 11:05:17
```

Output:

```
a   b                   c  
0   2020-03-03 15:46:52 1583279212
1   2020-03-02 11:05:17 1583175917
```

Comment: The `date` command would be the canonical way to retrieve the current or calculated time. Is there a reason you specifically ask for bash to calculate times/dates?

Comment: @JeffSchaller not really. I can use that. How can I add the new column?

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU `awk` and [mktime](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html):

```
awk '
  BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }
  FNR==1{ print $0, "c"; next }
  {
    split($2, a, /[ :-]/)
    print $0, mktime(a[1]" "a[2]" "a[3]" "a[4]" "a[5]" "a[6], 1)
  }
' file
```

- Use tab as input and output field separator
- Append `c` to the header line
- Split the second field into array `a` using a space character, `:` and `-` as separators
  and print the timestamp using the UTC flag

Output:

```
a       b       c
0       2020-03-03 15:46:52     1583250412
1       2020-03-02 11:05:17     1583147117
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how suitable it will be for large files, but you try do something like this with [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html)

```
$ TZ=UTC mlr --pprint --fs tab put -S '$c = strftime(strptime($b,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),"%s")' file
a   b                                   c
0   2020-03-03 15:46:52 1583250412
1   2020-03-02 11:05:17 1583147117
```

(although I just noticed it appears to screw up the header alignment when the OFS is tab ...).

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `date` in `bash` or any other shell that supports process substitutions:

```
$ paste file <( echo c; date -u -f <( cut -f 2 file | sed 1d ) +%s )
a       b       c
0       2020-03-03 15:46:52     1583250412
1       2020-03-02 11:05:17     1583147117
```

The innermost process substitution, `<( cut -f 2 file | sed 1d )`, produces the second column of the original data (the timestamps), with the header removed.  These timestamps are fed into GNU `date` through its `-f` option from the process substitution, and they are converted to Unix seconds using the output format string `%s`. The `-u` option to GNU `date` makes it print UTC time instead of local time.

The outer process substitution, `<( echo c; date ... )`, outputs the header for the new column, and then produces the data for that column.

This is then pasted as a new column of the existing data using `paste`.